# What is the difference between these function declarations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, declaration

I am having a hard time understanding what the difference between the following declarations is...

```
var User = function(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
};
```

and

```
function User(name, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
};
```

Comment: function expression vs function declaration

Comment: You may find this explanation helpful: http://thoughtsonscripts.blogspot.com/2012/01/javascript-anonymous-functions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I know the very basic difference is `var User = function(name, email)` is created at runtime, and `function User(name, email)` will be created at parse time.

adding example

This will work here because `name` is available when it parsed the file

```
name();    
function name () {
    console.log('My Name')
}
```

But this will throw an error called `undefined is not a function`

But here problem was it won't be declared until it read the line `var name = function()`.

```
name()
var name = function(){
    console.log('My Name');
}
```

Comment: "Parsing" is usally the process where some data is converted to another representation. So e.g. with JS it could be from text to some kind of byte code (I don't actually know). But at that moment it's impossible to create any runtime objects (like a function).  The difference is that function declarations are evaluated before anything else.